# Determine the area of the triangle PQR and the volume of the tetrahedron PQRS?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products, cross-product

For which $a∈R$ are the points P= (−1,2,1), Q= (−11,0,1), R= (a,−1,4) and S=  (0,1,a)  vertices  in  a  tetrahedron?

Determine  the  area  of  the  triangle PQR and the volume of the tetrahedron PQRS for such values of $a$.  (Positively oriented ON-system assumed.)

---

I worked through it and found that in order for the 3 vectors that form the tetrahedron to be linearly independent, $a$ cannot be equal to 2. But how does this give us a fixed volume? I can only say that that the volume cannot be equal to $x$ given that a=2, but nothing more? I also know that the volume of a tetrahedron is 1/6 the volume of a parallelepiped made out of the same vectors, but dont know how this can help. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!! :)

Comment: The area will be different for different values of $a,$ so you need a formula for area in which $a$ appears. Similarly for volume. It seems clear that you were not expected to give a single fixed number for area and another one for volume.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I will attempt and this post it here to make sure :)

Comment: I got $\sqrt{490+32a+a^2}$ for the area and $\frac{a^2 +15a -34}{6}$ for the volume. Both for $a$ $\neq$  2